# Vue Leaflet not rendering map

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

I've the following code(below) and so far what I can see is white page, without any error on the console. I want to render map with markers.
I'm the beginner with Vue and maybe you can help me with that. I've followed some pages about leaflet, and similar code worked.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app"></div>
</template>

<script>
import Map from './components/Map.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Map
  }
}
</script>
```

**Map.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="map">
        <v-map :zoom="zoom" :center="center">
            <v-tilelayer :url="url" :attribution="attribution"></v-tilelayer>
            <v-marker :lat-lng="marker"></v-marker>
            <v-marker v-for="item in markers" :key="item.id" :lat-lng="item.latlng" @l-add="$event.target.openPopup()">
                <v-popup :content="item.content"></v-popup>
            </v-marker>
        </v-map>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue2Leaflet from 'vue2-leaflet';
import L from 'leaflet';  

  export default {
    name: 'map',
    components: {
        'v-map': Vue2Leaflet.Map,
        'v-tilelayer' :Vue2Leaflet.TileLayer,
        'v-marker': Vue2Leaflet.Marker,
        L
    },
    data() {
        return {
            zoom: 13,
            center: [47.413220, -1.219482],
            url: 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            marker: L.latLng(47.413220, -1.219482),

            markers: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    latlng: L.latLng(47.417220, -1.222482),
                    content: 'Hi! this is my popup data'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    latlng: L.latLng(47.417220, -1.25),
                    content: 'Another'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
  }
</script>


<style scoped>
@import "~leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

</style>
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate'
import router from './router'
import Vue2Leaflet from 'vue2-leaflet';
import L from 'leaflet';

Vue.use(VeeValidate)
Vue.use(Vue2Leaflet)
Vue.use(L);
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  Vue2Leaflet,
  L,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you inspected to see if there is anything in the dom? The map may be rendered, but height / width is not set

Comment: @SølveTornøe how can I check it? In console on web browser I don't see anything.

Comment: Not in the console. If you open your inspector(f12), then click the elements tab then you can click your way trough the html. See if maybe the map container is 0x0 when you hoover it in the inspector.

Comment: Have you found the reason/fix for this?

Answer (score 5):

May be in code

```
<v-map :zoom="zoom" :center="center">
```

add attribute

```
style="height: 850px; width: 500px"
```

to succeed

```
<v-map :zoom="zoom" :center="center" style="height: 850px; width: 500px">
```

Comment: I needed to set the height

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this in main.js file:

```
import { Icon } from 'leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'

delete Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;

Icon.Default.imagePath = '.';
Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
  iconRetinaUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png'),
  iconUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'),
  shadowUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't give the height to the map component.

Here is the fixed code:

```
 <v-map :zoom="zoom" :center="center" style="height: 700px; width:600px">
        <v-tilelayer :url="url" :attribution="attribution"></v-tilelayer>
        <v-marker :lat-lng="marker"></v-marker>
        <v-marker v-for="item in markers" :key="item.id" :lat-lng="item.latlng" @l-add="$event.target.openPopup()">
            <v-popup :content="item.content"></v-popup>
        </v-marker>
    </v-map>
```